Dark mode doesn't work with nvidia drivers in 24.04
I have a Razer laptop with the usual integrated + nvidia graphics combo.
I cannot get the dark mode to apply to my system apps (nautilus, setting, etc.) when using the latest nvidia drive (550, installed from apt), nor any of the other nvidia drivers available in my Software & Updates app. This problem appears on both Wayland and Xorg. Also I didn't have that problem prior to the installation of 24.04 (I was running 23.10 before).
I could use Nouveau, and dark mode works fine with it, but when doing so I cannot use my second monitor.
I found some people having the same problem, but no solution proposed.
Do you guys have a fix for that?
Thanks you all!
(also I don't know if that is relevant, but sometimes my pc freezes, forcing me to force reboot.)

Well. After several reboots, it appears to be worse than just not working. It is randomly working! I'll keep that updated

Hey, similar issue here. Just upgraded fromo 22.04 with the same integrated + nvidia GPU combo. I have the nvidia-driver-550 installed from Software and Update panel.
It will turn ON automatically at sunset, and turn off from the topright shortcut. But When I turn it back on after a movie for example, it doesn't come back. It sometimes work when I go in the screen settings, but not always...
